# writing a new module, map

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm writing a new `module` for `pulseaudio`.
The module is a `filt` so I need to read the current stream modify it and put the new stream in output.

I'm seeing the modules `echo cancel` and `virtual surround` but they uses `channel map`. I'm not sure about how `map` works.
Can someone explain me how a `map` works? When and why I should write a custom `map` in a filter module?